# Jest __dirname looks one layer too deep

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jestjs

I'm running Jest tests in an ExpressJS app. In `/build` I have two directories `/src` and `/test`. In addition to these two I have a `.pem` private key.

In my compiled code

```
const pathToKey = path.join(__dirname, "id_rsa_priv.pem");
```

but I receive the error

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../apps/server/build/src/id_rsa_priv.pem'
```

it's looking in `/src` when it should be one level higher. How do I set it one layer higher?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `..` to navigate one directory level up:

```
const pathToKey = path.join(__dirname, "..", "id_rsa_priv.pem");
```